# Splitting string command in ansible to many lines

Tags: ansible, jinja2

lets consider following command:

`command: "curl http://{{ my_server }}:1234/xaw?x={{ x }}&y={{ y }}&z={{ z }}""`

How to write it in many lines, like:

```
command:
  "curl http://{{ my_server }}:1234/xaw?
  x={{ x }}&
  y={{ y }}&
  z={{ z }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just append a "\" at the end of the line:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_server: "x"
        ax: "x"
        ay: "y"
        az: "z"
    - set_fact:
        yourCommand: "curl http://{{ my_server }}:\
        1234/xaw?x={{ ax }}\
        &y={{ ay }}\
        &z={{ az }}"
    - debug: 
        var: yourCommand
```